# Как включить защиту от копирования для Telegram бота?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, авторские-права

Есть бот в котором нужно включить защиту от копирования, нигде не найду, как это сделать.

В API ничего нет. Видел кучу ботов, в которых запрещено копирование. Как это сделать? Вот пример, где это есть:

https://help.bothelp.io/article/10926

Comment: Есть в документации: https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.toggleNoForwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простой пример:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "123", protect_content=True)
```

[Документация Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.toggleNoForwards)

[Документация pyTelegramBotAPI](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/sync_version/index.html)

Comment: Отдуши! Помог!!!

Comment: @Nikita Это хорошо, можете поставить галочку и голос вверх, чтобы остальные поняли, что мой ответ решил вашу проблему